# Can't format SD card after flashing .raw file

Tags: sd-card

I have a micro SD card in a SD card adapter that I flashed with a fedora arm .raw file using Win32 Diskimager.  I have tried using diskpart, but it gives me a cyclic redundancy check.  chkdsk says that it can't run on an SD card formatted as RAW.  Minitool partition software and EaseUS partition software just return errors if I try to format.  sdcard.org's own sd card format utility says it doesn't support the SD card (I'm assuimg because it is in RAW format).  I have no idea how to fix this.  I'm not looking to recover anything, I just need to format it.  I think Windows itself has a problem with reading the disk (I checked the SC card slider it is in the unlocked position) just because windows itself does not support RAW format.  It recognizes that disk J: is there, but if I click on it in file manager it just says nothing is in the drive and it dissappears.  Is my only option left to use Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open CMD as administrator, and give the command `diskpart`.

Diskpart will open, type in `list disk` to list available disks, based on size, find out which one is the SD card. If you have found it, note the number and type the following command, where X is the number of the disk: `select disk X`.
Now the disk is selected and you should be able to clean it using the command `clean`. This will erase everything of the SD card and should allow you to format it again the normal way.

Before you do this, be VERY VERY sure you have selected the right disk, otherwise you might delete data you do not want to delete!

Comment: I've already tried that.  diskpart always runs as administrator, there is not option to run without.  What you have proposed returns me a cyclic redundancy check error.  I think it may be impossible to fix in Windows as Windows does not support cards formatted as RAW.

Comment: I'm sorry I read over it then. I said to run CMD as admin so diskpart opens in the same window and not seperately and asking for admin rights. Of course you could also directly open diskpart. By "cyclic redundancy check" do you mean an error? I do not know of any other method than what you have already done either.